# Ansible: Switch/Override variables depending on target inventory

Tags: ansible

I'm thinking about deploying rails apps on hosts in three different environments(prod/stag/dev) using Ansible. But struggling to set different `RAILS_ENV` for each host.

I've tried with the following setup.

Directory structure:

```
.
├── group_vars
│   └── app1.yml
├── inventories
│   ├── develop
│   │   └── group_vars
│   │        └── app1.yml
│   ├── production
│   └── staging
└── roles
```

`group_vars/app1.yml`(for common vars across environments)

```
services:
  - name: app
    environment:
      {env_vars other than RAILS_ENV}: foo
  - name: db
...
```

`inventories/develop/group_vars/app1.yml`(for inventory specific vars)

```
services:
  - name: app
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
```

It seems Ansible only looks at keys at top level when judging if the variable is already defined. So the `RAILS_ENV` in the second file gets unintentionally ignored.
(Not sure why inventory vars are lower in precedence order, I think it should be higher because it is more specific?)

Is there any clean way to do this?

Comment: Do you have the option of using ```host_vars``` ?

Comment: You are probably looking for the [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) and [hash behaviour](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour) docs of Ansible.

Comment: And so in the [hash behaviour article](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour) Ansible is advocating in favour of the use of the [`combine` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) in order to achieve what you are looking for. Will add an example with this later on.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you have a list inside `services` and not a dict? i.e. https://gist.github.com/b-enoit-be/bf14b9465ef4d5a96370100fe0afb28d. Also, is there an indent issue in your question, after `environment`? i.e. https://gist.github.com/b-enoit-be/8a407156c763da73eab40b48df0a1804

Comment: @souser I think `host_vars` are behind `group_vars` in terms of precedence so it gets overridden anyway

@β.εηοιτ.βε fixed indent in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the *hash behaviour* article of Ansible documentation:

> #### DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR
>
> **Description:** This setting controls how variables merge in Ansible. By default Ansible will override variables in specific precedence orders, as described in Variables. When a variable of higher precedence wins, it will replace the other value. Some users prefer that variables that are hashes (aka ‘dictionaries’ in Python terms) are merged. This setting is called ‘merge’. This is not the default behavior and it does not affect variables whose values are scalars (integers, strings) or arrays. We generally recommend not using this setting unless you think you have an absolute need for it, and playbooks in the official examples repos do not use this setting In version 2.0 a `combine` filter was added to allow doing this for a particular variable (described in Filters).

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour*</sup>
The recommended way to achieve this would be to use the [`combine`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) filter.

This said, you do have a list inside your dictionary, and this will make it quite a complex task to achieve.
Switching it to a dictionary would ease the pain:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      overridable_var: foo
  db:
    foo: bar
```

---

If I understand it properly, you are trying to put in place the [alternative directory layout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout) of Ansible best practices.

If this is the case, here could be a solution matching your use case, given that you can transpose your list inside `services` in a dictionary, as proposed above:

1. In the *group_var* files for each environment, prefix the `services` dictionary key by the name of the environment, e.g. `develop_services`

   ```yaml
   develop_services:
     app:
       environment:
         RAILS_ENV: development
         overridable_var: develop from inventories group_vars
   ```
2. In your playbook, as a first task, or even as a `pre_task`, `combine` the `services` dictionary with the one matching your environment, which you can get as part of your [`inventory_file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) path:

   ```yaml
   pre_tasks:
     - set_fact: 
         services: "{{ services | combine(vars[inventory_file.split('/')[-2] ~ '_services'], recursive=True) }}"
   ```

Then just use it.

Given the directory layout:

```
.
├── group_vars
│   └── app1.yml
├── inventories
│   ├── develop
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   └── app1.yml
│   │   └── hosts
│   └── staging
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   └── app1.yml
│       └── hosts
└── play.yml
```

*group_vars/app1.yml*

```yaml
services:
  app:
    environment:
      bar: foo
      overridable_var: from root group_vars
      do_not_override_me: from root group_vars
  db:
      engine: postgres
```

*inventories/develop/hosts*

```yaml
all:
  children:
    app1:
      hosts:
        app:
```

*inventories/develop/group_vars/app1.yml*

```yaml
develop_services:
  app:
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      overridable_var: develop from inventories group_vars
```

*inventories/staging/hosts*

```yaml
all:
  children:
    app1:
      hosts:
        app:
```

*inventories/staging/group_vars/app1.yml*

```yaml
staging_services:
  app:
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: staging
      overridable_var: staging from inventories group_vars
```

*play.yml*

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
     
  pre_tasks:
    - set_fact: 
        services: "{{ services | combine(vars[inventory_file.split('/')[-2] ~ '_services'], recursive=True) }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ services }}"
```

Running it for `develop` would give the recap:

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml -i inventories/develop

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [app]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [app] => {
    "msg": {
        "app": {
            "environment": {
                "RAILS_ENV": "development",
                "bar": "foo",
                "do_not_override_me": "from root group_vars",
                "overridable_var": "develop from inventories group_vars"
            }
        },
        "db": {
            "engine": "postgres"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
app                        : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Running it for `staging` would give the recap:

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml -i inventories/staging

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [app]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [app] => {
    "msg": {
        "app": {
            "environment": {
                "RAILS_ENV": "staging",
                "bar": "foo",
                "do_not_override_me": "from root group_vars",
                "overridable_var": "staging from inventories group_vars"
            }
        },
        "db": {
            "engine": "postgres"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
app                        : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

***An extra note:*** mind that this would not allow the playbook to be run on two environment at the same time, as pointed by the note under the section *using multiple inventory sources* of the documentation:

> Keep in mind that if there are variable conflicts in the inventories, they are resolved according to the rules described in [How variables are merged](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-we-merge) and [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#ansible-variable-precedence). The merging order is controlled by the order of the inventory source parameters. If `[all:vars]` in staging inventory defines `myvar = 1`, but production inventory defines `myvar = 2`, the playbook will be run with `myvar = 2`. The result would be reversed if the playbook was run with `-i production -i staging`.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#using-multiple-inventory-sources*</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change `services` to a dict, since a lot of other playbooks are referring to this.
But I think your answer looks like the best way to achieve what I want to do. I might try this if I have a chance to revamp all the code base someday. Thanks!